# error while sending a refund form with axios

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have this refund form that when it's filled on the frontend an email get sent on the backend. However, when i tested it on the forntend it gave me a sucess alert but the email wasn't sent so i consoled logged the response (as shown in `.then` after the post method in the code bellow) and i'm getting a server error. any idea what is wrong with my code??
p.s: i have tested the backend on postman and it works just fine.

frontend code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { setAlert } from "../actions/alert";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import Logo from "../assets/images/logo.png";

const Refusjon = ({ setAlert }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, []);

  const history = useHistory();
  const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    address: "",
    subject: "",
    amount: "",
    date: "",
    message: "",
    kontonm: "",
  });

  const [refusjonData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData);
  const [refusjonBilde, setRefusjonBilde] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if([e.target.name]=='image'){
      setRefusjonBilde({
        image: e.target.files,
      });
      // console.log(e.target.files);
    }else {
      updateFormData({
        ...refusjonData,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim(),
      });
    }
  };

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("name", refusjonData.name);
    formData.append("email", refusjonData.email);
    formData.append("address", refusjonData.address);
    formData.append("subject",'Refusjon');
    formData.append("amount", refusjonData.amount);
    formData.append("date", refusjonData.date);
    formData.append('image', refusjonData.image);
    formData.append("message", refusjonData.message);
    formData.append("kontonm", refusjonData.kontonm);
    axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/skjema/`, formData, config)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data));
        setAlert("Skjemaet ble sendt", "success");
        setLoading(false);
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setAlert("Skjema ble ikke sendt! Prøv igjen", "danger");
        setLoading(false);
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      });
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="py-5 text-center">
        <img
          className="d-block mx-auto mb-4"
          src={Logo}
          width="400"
          height="100"
          alt=""
        />
        <h2 className="text-muted">Lag et nytt arrangement</h2>
      </div>

      <form>
        <div className="ml-5 pl-4 w-75">
          <div className="form-group row">
            <label className="col-2 col-form-label" htmlFor="navn">
              Navn*
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control col-10 m-2"
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="name"
              required
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group row">
            <label className="col-2 col-form-label" htmlFor="epost">
              Epost*
            </label>
            <input
              type="email"
              className="form-control col-10 m-2"
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="email"
              required
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group row">
            <label className="col-2 col-form-label" htmlFor="address">
              Adresse*
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control col-10 m-2"
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="address"
              maxLength="200"
              required
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group row">
            <label className="col-2 col-form-label" htmlFor="amount">
              Beløp*
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control col-10 m-2"
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="amount"
              maxLength="10"
              required
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group row">
            <label className="col-2 col-form-label" htmlFor="message">
              beskrivelse*
            </label>
            <textarea
              type="text"
              className="form-control col-10 m-2"
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="message"
              rows="3"
              required
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group row">
            <div className="col-md-7">
              <label className="ml-2 pt-2" htmlFor="date">
                Dato*
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control m-2 w-75"
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="date"
                placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-5">
              <label className="ml-2 pt-2" htmlFor="image">
                Velg et bilde*
              </label>
              <input
                type="file"
                className="form-control-file mb-3"
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="image"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group row">
            <label className="col-2 col-form-label" htmlFor="kontonm">
              Kontonummer*
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control col-10 m-2"
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="amount"
              maxLength="40"
              required
            />
          </div>


          <button
            className="btn btn-primary m-2"
            type="submit"
            onClick={onSubmit}
          >
            Send
          </button>

        </div>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Refusjon.propTypes = {
  setAlert: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default connect(null, { setAlert })(Refusjon);
```

backend code

```
class Refusjon(APIView):

    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]


    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = RefusjonSerializer(data=request.data)

        data = self.request.data

        try:
            ri = Refusjon(image = data['image'])

            body =(
            'navn :' + data['name'],
            'epost :' + data['email'],
            'adresse :' + data['address'],
            'Sum :' + data['amount'],
            'dato :' + data['date'],
            'konto nummer: ' + data['kontonm'],
            'melding :' + data['message'],)


            bodyStr = str(body)

            msg = EmailMessage('Refusjon',bodyStr ,'info@gmail.com',['admin@gmail.com'],headers={'Message-ID': 'foo'})
            msg.content_subtype = "html"

            mime_image = MIMEImage(ri.image.read(),_subtype=str(ri.image.name).split(".")[-1])
            mime_image.add_header('Content-ID', '<image>')
            msg.attach(mime_image)

            msg.send()
            return Response({'success': 'Skjemaet ble sendt'})
        except:
            return Response({'error': 'Skjemaet kunne ikke sendes! Prøv igjen.'})
```

Comment: its means error on your server-side, client-side has no issue.

Comment: Always include the specific error. We can't see your back end code or guess what that error might be

Comment: @ZiaurRehman but i have tested the server side with postman multiple times and it worked

Comment: issue in your `config` you have to update "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" instead of 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

and `image: e.target.files` to `image: e.target.files[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the headers. Use the below content-type. `application/json` is for when you are sending raw JSON objects. If you are sending file(s) with the form use `multipart/form-data`. You will also have to appropriately handle this on the backend.

```
headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
```

Comment: i have already tried that and it's still not working. However when i tested this on the backend i hade the headers on application/json and it worked

Comment: I'm guessing you tested it with postman. Did you try sending a file with postman when the headers were set to `application/json`?

Comment: yes it was postman, and i sent an image and it worked with both actually i have just tested  'multipart/form-data' as well

Comment: I'm guessing you went into the body tab to create the request in postman, chose formdata from the provided options to upload the image, because that is the only way to upload a file with postman. In that case, postman adds the `multipart/form-data` as headers without you prompting it to do it, and it would have overridden your `application/json`.

Comment: yea i think u r right but i also have changed the code on the frontend and it's still not working :(

Comment: Try adding the `Accept` header as well like in my post. Also, log your error message on server and see what's going on. If possible share it here, it would help a great deal.

Comment: i added that and now finaly i'm getting that there is an error on the frontend and on the backend i got that the reponse is not accepytable